# Como obtener un valor de input type=text para hacer una confirmación dentro de un modal? C#

Tags: html, c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, modal

Necesito una confirmación del usuario dentro del Modal, pero no se como obtener ese valor que el usuario escribio en el input type ="text".
También me ayudaria si me explican como hacer que al dar en el boton aceptar del modal se redirija a otra vista. Soy nuevo en esto, gracias.

```css
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <label>
            Ingrese el Código del Cliente a facturar:
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="Codigo" />

        <div id="Factura" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="FacturaLabel" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="FacturaLabel">Factura</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Esta seguro que el codigo del cliente es: @Request["Codigo"]</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Factura">
                Facturar
            </button>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mejor sería que crees una función javascript para poder pasar la información del formulario al modal de forma dinámica.

Por lo tanto, quita el Request del modal y mejor pon un label con un id, ya que desde la función pondrás el valor ahí.

Dicho esto, la vista quedaría así:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <label>
            Ingrese el Código del Cliente a facturar:
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="Codigo" />

        <div id="Factura" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="FacturaLabel" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="FacturaLabel">Factura</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Esta seguro que el codigo del cliente es: <label id="codigoCliente"></label></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Factura">
                Facturar
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Y la función, así:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Factura').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        //Capturo el valor
        var codigo = $('[name="Codigo"]').val();
        //Pongo el valor en el campo del modal
        $('#codigoCliente').html(codigo);
    });
});
```

Comment: Gracias Ferran, me sirvió mucho ya pude hacer que el valor aparezca en el modal. Pero ahora necesito que ese mismo valor se me guarde en una variable en el C#, alguna idea de cómo lo puedo resolver ?

Comment: Efectivamente, al igual que haces para que muestre la vista (mediante un [HttpGet]), tienes que hacer lo mismo para capturar el valor, pero haciendo un [HttpPost]